# "How can I recover funds in Remix after a failed Flash Loan process on Ethereum?"

Tags: flash-loans, failed-transaction

While executing the contract, the transaction failed on Remix.eth. I would like to know how I can retrieve the Ethereum I deposited for the transaction. I am new to flash loans. Please help.
Hash - 0x001e2b7dE757bA469a57bF6b23d982458a07eFcE

Comment: Noted will use TestNet going forward. However, do you know how long it takes to get the money back? I did this 14 hours ago and still no refund. Thank you for your help. Below is transaction ID of the contract.
0xd1de2af6a2651aca254165c63478fa2ab623f40f8416f668b24a07644e9fb4f6

Comment: There's nothing like "refunds" in Ethereum network. A transaction either succeed or fail. A failed transaction will revert any changes but take the transaction fees. A successful transaction persist changes and finish. If you have more doubts please create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The hash you provided is an Ethereum address. The address in Ethereum mainnet has a few transactions touching it, and they have all succeeded.

If you issued a transaction which failed, you should most likely get most of your money back. It gets credited automatically to the wallet which issued the transaction.

In any case, never experiment on the mainnet. If you want to test things, do that either in a testnet or fork mainnet locally and try it there. Most likely it's easier for you to use a testnet for testing.

I repeat: if you are not absolutely sure of what you're doing don't use mainnet.